# aiohttp server - delete file after FileResponse return

Tags: aiohttp

I need to delete a temporary created file after it is returned to a request.
The used method looks like:

```
async def getBackup(self, request):
    context = request.rel_url.query['sn']
    filePath = createBackup(context)
    return web.FileResponse(
        path=filePath,
        headers={
            hdrs.CONTENT_TYPE: 'application/tar+gzip',
            hdrs.CONTENT_DISPOSITION: f"attachement;filename=backup.tar.gz;filename*=UTF-8''backup.tar.gz;",
            hdrs.CACHE_CONTROL: 'no-cache'
        }
    )
    # os.unlink(filePath) after file has been served ....
```

I searched for a signal or callback approach but did not find anything in the documentation.
Any hint or suggestions to make it done?

Comment: did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Could you put it inside a context manager or a try/finally?  For example:

```py
async def get_backup(self, request):
    async with aiofiles.tempfile.TemporaryFile('wb') as fp:
        await create_backup(fp)
        return web.FileResponse(path=fp.name)
```

Or the slightly uglier...

```py
async def get_backup(self, request):
    file = await create_backup()
    try:
        return web.FileResponse(path=file)
    finally:
        await sleep(1) # perhaps not needed
        await aiofiles.os.remove(file)
```